# Remove label created on Run-time CF C#

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, label

I create a label "label1" dynamically in a method. Then when I click a button I want to remove that label created but if I write *Controls.Remove(label1)* it says that the control doesn't exist in the context. 
How could I do to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Following Jon suggestion I implemented the foreach loop but it doesn't do anything. This is my code, the *panel* which I use is created by design:

```
void GenerateControls() {
    Label labelOne = new Label();
    Button btnContinue = new Button();
    panel.SuspendLayout();
    SuspendLayout();
    //btnContinue
    btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    btnContinue.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Menu;
    btnContinue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 272);
    btnContinue.Name = "btnContinue";
    btnContinue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 28);
    btnContinue.TabIndex = 13;
    btnContinue.Text = "Continue";
    btnContinue.Visible = true;
    Controls.Add(btnContinue);
    btnContinue.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnContinue_Click);            
    //labelOne            
    labelOne.Location = new Point(0,65); 
    labelOne.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,20);
    labelOne.Text = "labelOne";
    labelOne.Name = "labelOne";
    labelOne.Visible = true;
    labelOne.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lbl_TextChanged);
    labelOne.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
    Controls.Add(labelOne);
    //panel
    panel.Controls.Add(labelOne);
    panel.Visible = true;
    panel.Location = new Point(0,0);
    panel.Size = new Size(240, 320);
    //
    Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.ResumeLayout();
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

And then in when I click on *btnContinue*:

```
private void btnContinuar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls) {
        if (control.Name == "labelOne"){
            panel.Controls.Remove(control);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I debug it and in the panel.Control it continues as if it were empty panel.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let's see the code that created the label and assigned it to a container. It's possible you're not using the correct Label instance reference.

Comment: I already debug it using a BreakPoint, that was how I find out that it wasn't finding anything. More ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it says the *variable* doesn't exist in that context. You'll have to find the label by its text, or knowing something else about it. For example, when you create it you could set the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) property and find it by that when you want to remove it:

```
panel.Controls.RemoveByKey("YourLabelName");
```

EDIT: As noted in the comments, `RemoveByKey` doesn't exist in the compact framework. So you'd *either* have to remember the reference yourself (in which case you don't need the name) or use something like:

```
foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
{
    if (control.Name == "YourLabelName")
    {
        panel.Controls.Remove(control);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: And to make it even more "generic" and desktop compatible, you could keep the RemoveByKey call and add this to your app:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveByKey(this Control.ControlCollection collection,
                                   string key)
    {
        if(!RemoveChildByName(collection, key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key not found");
        }
    }

    private static bool RemoveChildByName(
        this Control.ControlCollection collection,
        string name)
    {
        foreach (Control child in collection)
        {
            if (child.Name == name)
            {
                collection.Remove(child);
                return true;
            }

            // Nothing found at this level: recurse down to children.
            if (RemoveChildByName(child.Controls, name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon is correct.  Just because you created it like Label label1 =new Label() doesn't make its name label1, you would then have to say label1.Name="label1";  Then you could remove it like you tried in your code. And Jon, slow down and let the rest of us answer some :)

Comment: Just as a small point of info, `RemoveByKey` doesn't exist in the Compact Framework, so you'd have to find it first (if you didn't aready have a reference dictionary), then remove it.

Comment: I tried the foreach loop but in the *panel.Controls* it doesn't find anything. I will edit my post adding my code.

Comment: @ctacke: In this case I think it would have been better as a separate answer, but I'll edit it to be the post I *would* have written :)

Comment: @JonSkeet could you find something wrong in my code? Thanks for your help

Comment: @nachogsiri: As per the other answer - you need to try to remove it from the same collection you add it to. It's very important that you *understand* your code - do you understand why it didn't work?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your help! I modified the code and made a mistake. This is my first time creating dynamic labels. I am learning and understanding code every time better thanks to all of you.

Comment: @nachogsiri I think This answer should be marked as THE ANSWER, mine does not reflect the question at all, and someone coming along later will be confused as to why this is THE ANSWER.  Go ahead and mark it as useful, but change the Answer to Jon's

Comment: Feel free to boost my answer though, you know since I was nice enough to give away rep points  :)

Answer (score 4):

After 20 edits to the OP question, and Jon's answer with no resemblance to the original problem, you are left with one small glitch.

Your Not adding labelOne to the panel you are adding it to the Form.

Change

```
Controls.Add(labelOne);
```

to

```
panel.Controls.Add(labelOne);
```

Then everything should work

Comment: Thanks!! I was adding labelOne to the panel AND to the form. When I add labelOne only to the panel the problem was solved.